# How to deal with code that depends on document.title in Next.js with SSG?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have 2 dynamic SSG pages under `/blog/[slug]`, inside of these pages I am rendering a component with `next/link`, I can click those links to go to another slug, the problem is that I want to run some code that depends on `document.title`, I tried a combination of possible solutions:

```js
const ref = createRef<HTMLDivElement>()

useEffect(() => {
  while (ref.current?.firstChild) {
    ref.current.firstChild.remove()
  }

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    if (typeof window === "object") {
      const scriptElement = document.createElement("script")
      scriptElement.src = "https://utteranc.es/client.js"
      scriptElement.async = true
      scriptElement.defer = true
      scriptElement.setAttribute("crossorigin", "annonymous")
      scriptElement.setAttribute("repo", "my/repo")
      scriptElement.setAttribute("issue-term", "title")
      scriptElement.setAttribute("theme", "photon-dark")

      ref.current?.appendChild(scriptElement)
    }
  }, 0)

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }
}, [])

...

return <div ref={ref} />
```

The problem is that useEffect does not run when switching between pages, this code only works when I visit refresh my page, how can I work with this code when navigating between pages to make it work using a up to date document title?

Edit:

```js
const BlogPost = ({
  recordMap,
  post,
  pagination,
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
  if (!post) {
    return null
  }

  const [script, setScript] = useState<HTMLScriptElement | null>(null)
  const ref = createRef<HTMLDivElement>()
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = () => {
      const scriptElement = document.createElement("script")
      scriptElement.src = "https://utteranc.es/client.js"
      scriptElement.async = true
      scriptElement.defer = true
      scriptElement.setAttribute("crossorigin", "annonymous")
      scriptElement.setAttribute("repo", "daniellwdb/website")
      scriptElement.setAttribute("issue-term", "title")
      scriptElement.setAttribute("theme", "photon-dark")
      setScript(scriptElement)
    }

    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange)

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (script) {
      ref.current?.appendChild(script)
      setScript(null)
    } else {
      ref.current?.firstChild?.remove()
    }
  }, [script])

  return (
    <>
      <Box as="main">
        <Container maxW="2xl" mb={16}>
          <Button as={NextChakraLink} href="/" variant="link" my={8}>
             Back to home page
          </Button>
          <NotionRenderer
            className="notion-title-center"
            recordMap={recordMap}
            components={{
              // Bit of a hack to add our own component where "NotionRenderer"
              // would usually display a collection row.
              // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
              collectionRow: () => <BlogPostHero post={post} />,
              code: Code,
              equation: Equation,
            }}
            fullPage
            darkMode
          />
          <Pagination pagination={pagination ?? {}} />
          <Box mt={4} ref={ref} />
          <Footer />
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the [router.events](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url, { shallow }) => {
      //...
    }
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I tried to implement it and I console log `ref.current` but it shows up as null the moment it runs, I have edited the question to include the code, the title does change properly now when I log that

Comment: Are you listen on routeChangeComplete in some parent component and ref is linked to a node in that parent component?

Comment: No the ref is in the same component

Comment: I can't reproduce your case, useEffect should run on every route change and ref.current should have value. Can you add the [slug] code, at least the most important part, I will try to reproduce it

Comment: I made another edit to show the full component, I also got the current edit to work, except out of nowhere I got `NoModificationAllowedError: Modifications are not allowed for this document`, alternatively I have a link to the [repository](https://github.com/daniellwdb/website), from the start there are 2 posts and when you navigate between them using the pagination at the bottom of the post, the comments should refresh

Comment: Where this error is originated NoModificationAllowedError?

Comment: It’s coming from utterances.js, the stack trace is not very useful, it points to parcelRequire, if you have the repo locally you can see it by changing the BlogPost component to the component in my edit

Comment: I downloaded  your code, but I am getting some error from this @/lib/notion because getAllPages return nothing, do I need to run some command before the npm run dev?

Comment: copy .env.local.example to .env.local

Comment: I will consider my new issue out of the scope for this question and will create a new one, thank you